# Periodic ground state 1-dim ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

Good evening!
I'm at the beginning of my study about the Ising model and it has been proposed to me this problem: 
Find all periodic ground-state configuration for the following one-dimensional Ising model of interacting spins, $s_i=+1$ or $ -1 $ 
$$
H=-\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} (s_{i}s_{i+1}-s_{i}s_{i+2}-4s_{i}s_{i+3})
$$
Actually, I don't know how to procede. I know that the ground states, by definition, are the configuration of minimal energy. But then, is this possible to compute these configuration for this specific model in an explicit way? 
I hope that someone could give me a hint, because I think that I'm a little bit confused.. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The state with minimal energy will be an alteration of +1 and -1 spins. The reason is that the 1-4 interactions will dominate the rest. Each spin in your system will interact with 6 others. Even though 1-2 (neighbours) and 1-3 interactions will be unfavourable in the alternating sequence, two favourable 1-4 interactions with the weight -4 will have more impact.

You can probably make this more rigorous by showing that flipping a single spin or creating a domain with different alternation will require positive energy.

Hope this helps.